# Laravel working through storage disk with files starting with dot

Tags: laravel, filesystems, digital-ocean, forge, hidden-files

I have to keep and work wiht some files in a filesystem on Laravel 5.2
I have a custom disk:

```
'modules_templates' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root'   => storage_path().'/modules_templates',
```

],

Just subfolder in storage folder
Everything works great at local machine, but now I'm trying to deploy my app at forge.laravel (above digitalocean) and when I try to get a file starting with dot (ex. ".description.php") I get not found exception
However there is no problem with normal files

Maybe I should use specific environment variable or there is no way to retrieve hidden files on this two services?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in difference of directory separator
It is strange that it only affects on fidden files